# radio button is checked, still isChecked() returns false in android

Tags: android

I'm facing problem with radio buttons in my activity. I have added two radio buttons in a radiogroup.

```
<RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/site_automation_yes"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="YES"
                        android:button="@drawable/apptheme_btn_radio_holo_light"
                        android:textSize="18dp"/>
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/site_automation_no"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="NO"
                        android:button="@drawable/apptheme_btn_radio_holo_light"
                        android:textSize="18dp"/>
                </RadioGroup>
```

When I check site_automation_yes radioButton, isChecked() still returns false. 
Also for the very first time when the activity is created, I'm unable to check the "site_automation_no" radio button. But when I check the site_automation_yes first, then I am able to check and uncheck both the radio buttons. But for the site_automation_yes isChecked always return false,irrespective of whether it is checked or not. Can someone tell me how to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the checked radio then you have to follow this :
1. Give id to radio group
2. Use below example :

```
int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

// find the radiobutton by returned id
radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here, radioSexGroup is a RadioGroup id. Get checked radio button by getCheckedRadioButtonId(); then simply get the name of checked radio button.

Comment: What if both are unchecked?

Comment: If you want to pre selected any option then you don't have to check null at radioSexButton. If you don't want pre select any option then check for null on radioSexButton.

Comment: I have to keep both unselected initially.

Comment: Just check if(radioSexButton != null) then do something else not.

Comment: isChecked problem is solved. but the other part of the question is still unanswered.

Comment: Your above xml code working fine in my app. I am able to select first time or anytime No radio button in app.

Comment: This issue was not occurring earlier,and it occurs sometimes with some of the radio buttons in my layout.

Comment: I have just stored the value of the checked radio button to my db,nothing else.